# Single machine domain with Windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, domain-controller

Is it possible to setup one single machine with Windows 7 x64 OS and somehow make it work as if it's part of a certain domain? So domain controller would be simulated in some way? I would like to avoid VMs and make it actually work on one machine with non server OS.

Is there even a simpler way of doing it?
Maybe some third-party software that can be installed on a non-server OS?

> **Why**: I have to setup development environment for Sharepoint 2010 and it will make my life much easier if my machine would be part of a domain.

Comment: Downvote? It's just a question about something someone doens't know. That's why `serverfault.com` is for, isn't it?

Comment: Just by saying you want it to work with a non-server OS, effectively ends what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim: It is. That something is *single machine with both on them* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It can't be done the way you want.

Longer answer: It can't be done the way you want because you can't simulate a domain. You either have one or you don't and you can't do that on a Windows workstation OS. The nearest you'll get without a Windows DC is to use Samba. Of course you can't do that either, because you don't want a VM or another machine.

Comment: Has Samba improved Active Directory domain support? Last I looked at it Samba was primarily used to simulate older style Windows domains, not Active Directory, and AD support was beta at best and lacking some features.

Comment: I don't know but the point is moot as it doesn't fit the specified criteria anyway. I must admit I haven't tried Samba for at least 5 or 6 years.

Answer (score 1):

Without a VM on another machine or turning your machine into a Windows Server domain controller, not really, no. Domains aren't meant for testing or simulating this way.

Comment: Maybe not testing, but development definitely. Which is a kind of test anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a virtual machine acting as a domain controller on your box. That's the only way as far as i know.

Comment: It would be great if I could run a thin VM before user logs in, so it would be possible to log into domain.

Comment: You can use VmWare Server.